# Unable to retrieve varchar(max) fields using VB6 ADO on SQL Server with ODBC 13 drivers

Tags: sql-server, vb6, odbc, ado

We have a VB6 application using ADO and needed to update the SQL Server ODBC drivers to handle TLS 1.2 compliancy.  I am able to query a varchar(max) field using the original {SQL Server} driver, but any newer ODBC driver will not return varchar(max) fields (13, 11, SQL Native Client 11, 10, etc.).  All the other fields field types return fine with newer drivers, except the varchar(max).

I am setting my database connection string as follows:

```
PROVIDER=MSDASQL;Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=server;DATABASE=dbname;UID=user;PWD=password;DataTypeCompatibility=80;MARS Connection=True;
```

Then executing the ADO recordset using:

```
Set recordset1 = gsSQLConn.Execute(strSQL, recordsaffected, adCmdText)
```

The SQL is

```
SELECT TABLE.NOTES AS [Value] From TABLE WHERE (((TABLE.NOTES) Is Not Null) AND ((TABLE.TABLE_ID)=#####))
```

where ##### is a valid integer ID for the table.

The return value shows as:

```
        2                                                      à
```

and is type 200 (adVarChar).

I am at a loss on this one, and not sure why I cannot get the newer ODBC drivers to read the varchar(max) fields.  I did look into the SQLGetData function, but not quite sure how to get it working for my scenario, or even if it's necessary.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b59ae1ba-1add-4a93-845e-e4505603d23f/selecting-varcharmax-or-nvarcharmax-columns-using-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-results-in?forum=sqldataaccess?

Comment: Thank you so much!  The "garbage characters" nailed it.  I was actually able to use SQLOLEDB (a little older) instead of MSOLEDBSQL without any problems.  I previously was using MSDASQL to no avail, and even tried other providers (as I came from the DAO world with VB6).